# php cal function with hash table like parameter

Tags: php, function, parameters, expression

I defined a function which I want to use hash table like parameter inside.

```
function Foo($param)
{
   // Here, I should get fener as key, and bahce as value. 
}

Foo('fener' => 'bahce'); // Is there a way like .net's lambda expression ?
```

And I don t want to use `Foo(array('fener' => 'bahce'))` // it is possible I know..

Comment: PHP arrays *are* hash tables from what I understand. What's wrong with using them?

Answer (score 1):

One way or the other you will have to declare your array with `array()`:

```
$args = array('fener' => 'bahce');
Foo($args);
```

or directly:

```
Foo(array('fener' => 'bahce'));
```

**Edit**

As of PHP 5.4 you can also do (from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)):

```
// as of PHP 5.4
$array = [
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
];
```

So you might get away with:

```
Foo(['fener' => 'bahce']);
```